# What model to use to evaluate whether the "variability" of one variable is determined by the "variability" of other variables?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, variability

I have observations taken for four subjects at a number of points/locations. The data is formatted similarly to as below:

[image]

I am not directly interested in the impact that a predictor has on the response variable. Instead, I would like to evaluate whether the variability (e.g. standard deviation or some other measure that I have not considered) of the response variable at a given location is determined by the variability of the predictors.

How would I go about investigating this? I intend to use R, so I would be doubly appreciative of directions to a suitable package/model that can be implemented there.